# Herencia de clase python

Tags: python

Estoy intentando hacer una agenda en Python, las clases son:

- Direccion
- Persona
- Telefono

Luego tiene una clase Contacto que hereda las tres clases anteriores.

Dejo el código:

```
class Direccion:
    def __init__(self, calle, piso,ciudad, codigoPostal):
        self.calle = calle
        self.piso = piso
        self.ciudad = ciudad
        self.codigoPostal = codigoPostal
    
    def GetCalle(self):
        print(self.calle)
    def GetPiso(self):
        print(self.piso)
    def GetCiudad(self):
        print(self.ciudad)
    def GetCodigoPostal(self):
        print(self.codigoPostal)
    
    def SetCalle(self):
        self.calle = input("Introduzca la calle nueva: ")
    def SetPiso(self):
        self.piso = input("Introduzca el piso nuevo: ")
    def SetCiudad(self):
        self.ciudad = input("Introduzca la nueva ciudad: ")
    def SetCodigoPostal(self):
        self.codigoPostal = input("Introduzca el nuevo código postal: ") 

class Persona:
    def __init__(self, nombre, apellidos, fechaNacimiento):
        self.nombre = nombre
        self.apellidos = apellidos
        self.fechaNacimiento = fechaNacimiento
    
    def GetNombre(self):
        print(self.nombre)
    def GetApellidos(self):
        print(self.apellidos)
    def GetFechaNacimiento(self):
        print(self.fechaNacimiento)
    
    def SetNombre(self):
        self.nombre = input("Introduzca un nombre: ")
    def SetApellidos(self):
        self.apellidos = input("Introduzca los apellidos: ")
    def SetFechaNacimiento(self):
        self.fechaNacimiento = input("Introduzca la fecha de nacimiento: ")

class Telefono:
    def __init__(self, telefonoFijo, telefonoMovil, telefonoTrabajo):
        self.telefonoFijo = telefonoFijo
        self.telefonoMovil = telefonoMovil
        self.telefonoTrabajo = telefonoTrabajo
    
    def GetTelefonoFijo(self):
        print(self.telefonoFijo)
    def GetTelefonoMovil(self):
        print(self.telefonoMovil)
    def GetTelefonoTrabajo(self):
        print(self.telefonoTrabajo)

    def SetTelefonoFijo(self):
        self.telefonoFijo = input("Introduzca el número de teléfono fijo: ")
    def SetTelefonoMovil(self):
        self.telefonoMovil = input("introduzca el número de teléfono móvil: ")
    def SetTelefonoTrabajo(self):
        self.telefonoTrabajo = input("Introduzca el número de teléfono del trabajo: ")
    
class Contacto(Direccion,Persona,Telefono):
    def __init__(self, email):
        self.email = email

    def GetEmail(self):
        print(self.email)
    
    def SetEmail(self):
        self.email = input("Introduzca la dirección de correo electrónico: ")
    
    def MostrarContacto(self):
        print(self.nombre,self.apellidos,self.telefonoFijo)

persona1 = Persona("paco","martinez soria","08-11-1984")
casa1 = Direccion("paseo de soria","12","soria","10005")
telefono1 = Telefono("900123456","600639549","600639548")

c1 = Contacto()
c1.MostrarContacto()
```

Ahora quiero que al ejecutar MostrarContacto() me muestre la información como el nombre, telefono....

He creado algunos objetos para poder probar pero  me da error y no se que es lo que esta fallando.

La idea es poder introducir contactos pero antes de nada queria probar que me funcionara con datos de contacto ya creados, por separado si me muestra datos pero cuando lo hago a través de la clase Contacto es cuando me da el error, no se si se debe a los constructores o a los métodos

Espero puedan ayudarme.

Un saludo.

Comment: utiliza `super()` para inicializar todas las clases, hacerlo de la forma *tradicional* es muy tedioso.

Answer (score 2):

Una forma de arreglar tu error es recibir como parámetro, la instancia de cada clase (telefono, direccion, persona) y en el método `init` de la clase `Contacto` definar cada instancia como variable, una vez teniendo esto ya se podria acceder a los atributos de cada clase.

```py
class Contacto():
    def __init__(self,direccion,persona,telefono,email):
        self.email = email
        #creamos los atributos de acuerdo a la instancia de la clase que se recibe
        self.persona = persona
        self.direccion = direccion
        self.telefono = telefono

    def GetEmail(self):
        print(self.email)
    
    def SetEmail(self):
        self.email = input("Introduzca la dirección de correo electrónico: ")
    
    def MostrarContacto(self):
        # para acceder al atributo tenemos que indicar la clase (definido como atributo) 
        # y luego ingresar a su atributi como si fuese la propia clase (que en si lo es)
        # retornamos, de lo contrario al hacer un print saldria none
        return f"{self.persona.nombre},{self.persona.apellidos},{self.telefono.telefonoFijo}"
```

En esta caso eliminamos la herencia, pues si ya estas creando la instancia antes, ya no es necesario (y no tiene sentido) hacer la herencia. La herencia sirve utilizar los métodos y atributos de las clases padres, persona quien ya no sería necesario hacerlo de esa forma.

**probamos**

```py
persona1 = Persona("paco","martinez soria","08-11-1984")
casa1 = Direccion("paseo de soria","12","soria","10005")
telefono1 = Telefono("900123456","600639549","600639548")

c1 = Contacto(casa1,persona1,telefono1,"myemail@email.com")
print(c1.MostrarContacto())
```

**resultado**

```
paco,martinez soria,900123456
```

No estoy seguro si sea la forma correcta de hacer la implementación de tu clase `Contacto`, te sugiero aprender un poco mas de *POO*.

Comment: Muy bien sugiriendo la composición, pero ¿para qué dejas la herencia?

Comment: Me había olvidado que ya no era necesario, ahora lo quito. Gracias 